# My first program in Android Studio (Hello world)

Tags: android, android-studio

Everyone!!
I try to launch my first program in Android Studio. I have got error, something like this:

```
        Failed to refresh Gradle project 'Hello World'
        Cause: failed to find Build Tools revision 16.0.2
        Please install the missing Build Tools from the Android SDK Manager.
        Open Android SDK Manager
```

I installed Android SDK :
[image]

Honestly i don't see in my installations Android SDK Build-tools revision 16.0.2
I have googled to download this revision, but i couldn't find any refs... ??
Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: what SDK versions are listed in the `Manifest`?

Comment: @nikis       `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="android.support.v7.appcompat">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <application />
</manifest>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a very old version of Android Studio. Have a look at the `android` section in the `build.gradle` file in your project. Your screenshot shows that you have build-tools 19.0.3 installed, so change the appropriate line to

```
buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
```

And update your Android Studio so it won't produce outdated build.gradle files in the first place!

Comment: .Yes. It works now . I changed content of build.gradle to
           `android {
             compileSdkVersion 17
             buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"}`

Answer (score 0):

Find the root build.gradle file. It will look something like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 4
        versionName "0.9.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Change the buildToolsVersion to 19.0.3 and be sure you installed this build tools version. The latest version of Android Studio should give a notification if you use an outdated version of buldToolsVersion.

Small side note: Please be aware that Android Studio is still in beta. Not everything works perfectly at the moment. Nevertheless, I think it works already a lot better than Eclipse.